# Create truly working tables with fixed headers

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, gridstack

I'm trying to make the table with fixed header and auto-adjusted height to fill reaming space of wrapper div with *tbody*. I've spent over few days to solve the issue but every solution have it's own issues and I would love to ask you for help.

I'm working on *Vue* and *Gridstack* as I want to have resizable and draggable modules.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function () {
    $('.grid-stack.outer').gridstack({
      cellHeight: 80,
      verticalMargin: 20,
      horizontalMargin: 10
    });

    $('.grid-stack.inner').gridstack({
      cellHeight: 70,
      verticalMargin: 20,
      horizontalMargin: 10
    });
  });
});
```

I. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMpXrN
    - works on Mac (Chrome and Safari)
    - don't work on Windows, *Edge*: header is not fixed
    - don't work on Windows, *Chrome*: when scroll is visible on tbody, the headers does not mach the columns (tbody is moved); example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e730d7z4p10wpoe/Zrzut%20ekranu%202018-03-13%2011.20.30.png?dl=0)

II. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdpaKz
- works almost perfectly but if we scroll horizontally, the headers won't follow the content - example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jqe0b0k8a3qcr0v/Zrzut%20ekranu%202018-03-13%2011.25.18.png?dl=0

**Sum up:**
I've spent few days so far, trying to build working table. I've tried flexbox based tables (which worked great beside that it was no possibility to fix the headers), regular tables. I've failed miserably.
What I'm looking for is to create table that:
- won't require jQuery (it can use vanilla JS)
- have fixed header
- scroll horizontally both headers with content
- auto-adjust the width of the cells in case user will resize it (and keep the same width for both column and header for that column)

Is it truly something impossible to achieve? I event wanted to watch the width of column and adjust the width of header accordingly, but with gridstack, the DOM is not updating it's width in vue.

PS. I have to get regular DOM (not something like only injecting array of data) I can modify as there might be complex elements in table.

I've tried datatables but I cannot make it to fill the gridstack wrapper when it's resizing.

Thanks!